# How to use forgot password in login page in my application

Tags: java, android

I am following this tutorial http://www.linuxforu.com/2010/12/android-application-development-playing-with-sqlite-database/ for using login page in my android application,in this tutorial there is no explanation about forgot password,i want to add these feature also in my application.
MYLogin.java

```
public class UserLoggedInPage extends Activity {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loggedin);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onBackPressed()
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent i = new Intent(UserLoggedInPage.this, DatabaseActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="30dp"
    >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtUname"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
        ></TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editUsername"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
            android:textColor="#000000"
        >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row2"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
        ></TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
            android:password="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
        ></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        ></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNewUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonSignUp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        ></Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShowAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonShowAll"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        ></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

****Can anyone tell,how to use forgot password in my application,or give some links or tutorial to learn how to put forgot password in android,i am new to android****
```

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to do your job. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I want to integrate login page for my application,that why i tried to put login page and i got this tutorial for reference,but i felt that one thing is missing that is forgot password,i dont have any idea about how to do,if you have any links or you know means tell i will follow that one

Comment: Your question or objective is just a basic in android. If you don't have any idea it's because maybe you haven't learned or too lazy to study the basics. People here are ready to help your problems but not to do your job responsibility as developer.

Comment: @hardcoded,i having one doubt in that,if i will provide the button/link of forgot password in login pages,it has to go another activity it contains username or email,if they will provide correct user name or email,which one is correct it will fetches the pwd from database or  sending reset links to mail which one is good and how to do that one?

Comment: @hardcoded can you tell me some links for learning basic android and their functionality and UI

Comment: Have you tried searching on google? Android documentation docs - http://developer.android.com/index.html sqlite database tutorial for android - http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @thank you,is this possible to fetch the pwd from db and to display the pwd

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional link/button as "forget password".
On this button click,create new activity where you provide one edittext where he can insert username and check button to check whether this username exist in your database or not.

check user provided username ,compare it, show the result back.

Comment: I am new to android,can you please give some link how to do that one,i agree with you,thats nice concept you are telling,i want to put one button or link that forgot password in login page,if i click this it has to open one activity having username or email if he submits in the sense,it will displays his password,how to do this ?will you please tell

Comment: ,thanks nice idea you gave to me,if the user will give the correct user name,how it will retrieve the password from db,is this possible?or if user provides his email id,it has to sent the link of reset the password it is good or that one is good?how we can do which one is easy and correct

Comment: you really need to do research ..
work more on android.
for now you can compare values with database

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: check following link..
Basic all information :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: is this possible to fetch the pwd from db and display it?

Comment: Ya i am storing user name and pwd in db only

Comment: need to research:
1) android flow.
2)database connectivity -retrieve values
3)show to the user

Comment: ,can you give me some good links for learning basic android and their UI's

Comment: thank you,if you know that how to fetch from db and display my password